# What resolution should a mobile website be optimized for?

Tags: iphone, css, screen-resolution

I'm having trouble understanding how the mobile resolution works. From what I know, standard website mobile resolution is 320px width. The problem seems to be with iPhone 4, which seems to have 640px width screen resolution, but yet, it displays web in 320px.

What is the solution here? Do I code 2 different resolutions for 320px and 640px screens? How do I force iPhone 4 to display 640px web?

Comment: You can use different stylesheets using media queries wit min/max-width. Don't know about forcing a resolution on the Iphone. - Maybe jQuery Mobile is a spot to look what they did?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well basically, as you've noticed, iPhone 4+ resolution is 640px, but the browser only displays 320px of it, for a number of different reasons. Check this other answer for more details on how this is happening:[320px resolution for web apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864453/iphone-4-defaults-to-320px-resolution-for-web-apps-i-want-to-use-the-full-640p)

That also talks about the fact that you can specify the viewport for a website to force it to be seen in 640px on an iphone, but that you shouldn't do that, but just double the resolution on the image you use.

Answer (score 5):

I have found websites with a minimum width of 320px will look good on most high-end mobile devices like the iPhone, Android and Nokia N97.Some of the screen resolutions of  most popular devices:

"iPhone            320 x 480"

"iPhone 4       320 x 480 (scaled by a factor of 2)"

"HTC Legend     320 x 480"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for your post! Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)

Answer (score 1):

Either you can use an adaptive layout, like used on [this](http://colly.com/) website (try decrease the width of your browser window to see the site adapt). That design is also discussed in this [blog post](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/adaptive-layouts-media-queries).

Or you create separate layouts for different resolutions all together using [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/).

Comment: I didn't ask how to do it, I asked why iPhone 4, which has 640px screen, cannot display website bigger than 320px.

Comment: @RiMMER Because of something the marketing calls "retina display"

Comment: @RiMMER Btw, you didn't ask why the iPhone 4 has a 640 px screen but how to handle it. You got your answers...

Comment: @RiMMER Well, you asked "What is the solution?". One general solution is a design that adapts to the resolution of the browser, no matter the device. So I really don't understand the down vote.

Answer (score 1):

Because the number of pixels has doubled from iPhone 3 to iPhone 4, it would have meant every website optimized for the iPhone 3 would then be ... tiny on the display.
Hence, a devicePixelRatio was introduced, to retain the size of the websites (in mm or inches) while doubling the physical pixels, efficiently making double resolution (retina) images and fonts much sharper, but retaining old CSS font and pixel sizes.

The devicePixelRatio is 2:1 on iPhone 4 and 5. 
That means an image defined in css with 100100px will actually take up 200x200 physical pixels. So you can still css-style the page with 320px total width; 320 dips - device independent pixels.

Note that the devicePixelRatio also exists on Android, where it ranges from 1.5 up to 3.

More information: 
http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2012/06/devicepixelrati.html and 
http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2012/07/more_about_devi.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:portrait)" href="/Content/portrait.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:landscape)" href="/Content/landscape.css">
```

This way CSS will load separately for landscape and protrait.

```
@media (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 640px){}
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 400px){}
```

This is how the resolution will be handled.

Answer (score 0):

The most common mobile screen sizes are 320x240, 480x320, 800x480, 960x480, 1024x800, and  1024x768.

Comment: This answer is irrelevant

Answer (score -1):

you use this line of code:

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width: 480px)" />
```

When it detects your screen to be less than 480px in width, it will use that css. If not, it will use the normal css you used before

Comment: and within that mobile.css you can define css rules for potrait and landscape orientation. with this: @media screen and (orientation:portrait) { CSS IN HERE }

Comment: or for landscape @media screen and (orientation:landscape) { CSS IN HERE }

Comment: btw 480px is the width of the iphone4 display. I have no idea where you got 320px or 640px

Comment: From wikipedia: 640×960 resolution at 326 ppi (0.61 megapixels): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iphone_4

Comment: nevertheless you can change the 480px to 640px. In that way it will call the css when it detects the 640px width screen

Comment: That's just what I did - I coded a 640px website, but when I opened it in iphone4, I saw only half of it - 320px.

Comment: Just try the code i wrote as answer. And define some like body {display:none} and look back in your iphone 4 to see if anythings displays or not. If not, that means you're good to go.

Comment: These are all old guides written for iPhone 3GS, which had 480px screen.

Comment: well then change it to <link type="text/css" href="css/mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" /> as i said before and try it with the display:none to see if it works or not